# Heat Diffusion and Specific heat

Tags: mechanical-engineering, heat-transfer, thermal-conduction

Consider two slabs - Slab A and Slab B, insulated on "latereal" faces as shown, initially at the same temperature, and having identical dimensions. The slabs at t= 0 are brought in contact with two heat reservoirs (on left and right) at temperatures $T_1$ and $T_2$. Slabs have the same thermal conductivity but different specific heats, with $c_A > c_B$

Since specific heat of A > that of B I argue that the temperature profiles at any instant of time t, would be as follows:

[image]

i.e. since $c_A > c_B$ A will have a hard time raising it's temperature than B. As a result the temperature gradients in A will be smaller (in magnitude) than in the case of B. This would mean that the heat transferring to A from the left reservoir in any time dt is smaller in A than in B. Furthermore, the rate of heat transfer in intermediate layers will also be lower in A than B. I've often read that a higher specific heat restricts thermal diffusion, could this be one way of explaining it why?

Comment: Are you considering the steady state or the transient case?

Comment: @NMech Transient

Comment: You are describing a transient process, which lends itself to straightforward analysis that gives the temperature profile in the insulator and the bulk temperature of the slabs as a function of time.  But I don't see a concise question.  I suggest you re-write this with a clear question about what you want to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. What you are referring to maybe the property called **Thermal diffusivity, $\alpha$**

$$\alpha =\frac{k}{\rho C_p}$$

- Cp = specific heat
- k = thermal conductivity
- $\rho $= density
  So Thermal diffusivity is inversely related to specific heat.

However in your example as soon as slab A reaches the T2,
a bit after slab B, on the right side they both transfer heat at the same rate because they have the same thermal conductivity.

Comment: kamran, yes, I always had trouble wrapping my head around the concept of thermal diffusivity. I was reviewing my notes today, when this one of the ways of interpreting how high specific heat restricts thermal diffusion came to my mind.

Comment: It's like 2 12 volt batteries one larger one smaller. the larger takes more energy to charge, but once the 2 batteries are charged both have a voltage of 12.